# Work done by friction if a body is not purely rolling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, work, friction

[image]
A sphere is moving forward, sliding and turning such that it is **not** in a pure roll.

Therefore the point of contact may have some velocity, as I've shown in the figure by $v$.

Will friction do any work?

I think no, because friction won't exist for the contact point as soon as it moves.That is during $dr$ displacement of contact point the force on the contact point will be zero because it won't be in contact anymore.

I'd be grateful if someone helped me.

Comment: Friction will do work, However I don't understand why is the velocity of point of contact at an angle ?

Comment: Could you please explain how friction will do any work?

Comment: Do you just want the reason or also want to know much work  friction does ?

Comment: Only the reason,Thank you.

Comment: @Bhavay - You are right. The velocity is horizontal. It is pointing to the back if rotation is slow.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

After making the diagram , I realized there is no way to know whether friction will do work or not, unless more information is provided.

The net velocity$\hat i $ is given by : $v_0 - (v\cos\theta+ \omega r)  $

Friction won't do any work if the above sum is 0.

Since you mentioned , that the body is not in pure roll, It should indicate that the the net sum is not 0 and the friction will do some work as there is a relative displacement between point of contact and the ground.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that was why I was confused as well, but I believe the work is zero according to my above arguments.

Comment: @YasirSadiq Since you mentioned , when body is not in pure roll, It should indicate that the  the net sum is not.

Comment: 'when the force acts, it doesn't move. When it moves, the force doesn't act' –

Comment: You are right that you need more information to figure out how much work friction will do. But you know enough to say that friction will do work. There is some sliding going on, so the bottom point in contact with the plane for this instant is moving horizontally. Friction is exerting a horizontal force in the direction opposite to that motion. $dW = \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{d} < 0$. The body loses kinetic energy. Friction slows the motion.

Comment: @mmesser314 How do you know that some sliding is going on ? If the sum of the equation i wrote is 0 , Then static friction will act and hence no work will be done.

Comment: You are right that it is possible to arrange the rotation speed and translation speed so that the total velocity of the bottom point is $0$. But that is a pure roll. The OP said this is not a pure roll. But +1 for raising a good point.

Comment: The work will be positive then, increasing speed of the centre of mass

Comment: @YasirSadiq Speed can decrease also .

Comment: The center of mass will increase if the work is positive.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of no-sliding, there is a one to one mapping between the points of the surface of the roll and the ground. After any length $l$ of the circunference of the roll, corresponds the same length $l$.

In this case of braking sliding, there is a difference $\Delta l = l_g - l_r$, that is, the length on the ground is greater that on the roll. The work is the product of the friction force by that length difference (that is the path of the force).

$\Delta w = F_f \Delta l$

The friction is the net force in the roll, if we neglect air drag. So, we can write:

$\int_a^b F_f \Delta l = \frac{1}{2}mv^2|_a^b + \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2|_a^b$

The work done by the net force corresponds to the change of the kinetic energy. In the formula, $v$ is the velocity of the center of mass, $m$ the mass of the roll, $I$ its moment of inertia, and $\omega$ the angular velocity.

Comment: Thank you dear claudio Saspinsky.  Let's focus on the point in contact with the ground. That's where the friction acts.  So it must be that the contact point has a horizontal velocity as well and therefore is dragged along the surface and hence we've a work due to friction.

Answer (score 1):

Sliding friction does work on the sliding body because there is relative displacement between the sliding body and the surface upon which it slides; the point if contact does move (slide) before rotating away from the surface.  (Pure rolling friction does no work because there is no relative displacement.)

For a rigid body there is no dissipation of energy within the rigid body due to friction, so the force of sliding friction changes the kinetic energy of the sliding body without heating effects.  In reality no body is perfectly rigid and there are heating effects.

If you search this exchange for "sliding friction" you will find detailed discussions that will provide more details.