# What should the coefficient of friction be if I don't want a box I'm trying tip over to slide?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

Say I'm moving to a new house and my moving boxes are cubical and evenly packed. If I want to tip over/overturn one of the boxes by horizontally pulling on one of its upper edges, while balancing the box on the edge below that (see the drawing), the box may start sliding instead. How large should the (static) coefficient of friction between the box and the ground (at the very least) be if we don't want the box to slide?

[image]

My attempt: The friction force will be to the left and will originate from the edge which is in contact with the ground. Now, since both of the forces are horisontal, I think they should be equal to each other if we don't want the box to start sliding. But the friction force depends on the normal force i.e. the box's weight, and I don't know how I can relate that to the force that is pulling on the box. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Your question really comes off as "do my homework for me" which is off topic here. Please provide details in your question above describing your attempt(s) for solving this problem. Describe specific concepts that are confusing for you. Otherwise, this question will likely be closed as off topic.

Comment: [Toppling of a cylinder on a block](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95234/37364)

Answer (score 0):

At the critical point, the CCW torque produced by gravity about the lower right corner will be equal to the CW torque produced by the external force.