# Let's say I add +2 and +4 micro coulombs of charge on a 1micro farad parallel plate capacitor. How would the charges be distributed?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

I have been learning capacitors and I came across this problem where we are adding some charges to a parallel plate capacitor as mentioned above. I have no idea on how charges would be distributed across to the inner and outer plates of a capacitor so, I need help. Pls keep it simple

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/765198/