# Equivalency of Atomospheric Pressure on a Surface to Weight Load on Points

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I have a flat square of unit area on sea level. I know that the force exerted on it is approximately $ 10^5 N $. How can I equate this to weight loads on its vertices?
Is it right to say forces exerted on different locations can be added to give the same amount of force on the entire surface? How will this problem change if the surface is non-planar?
The fact that weight loads hanging from a point is different than force exerted on the entire surface confuses me a lot.

Edit:
If I can restate my question it would be as : How can I go from distributed force to point force?

Comment: This is unrelated, but it may help - [Toppling of a cylinder on a block](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95234/37364)

Comment: Do you know the difference between a point force and a distributed force?

Comment: Thanks for the comment especially because of @ChetMiller I edited my original question.

Comment: Is it a flat surface?  Is the force uniformly distributed?  Can you provide a schematic  for a specific example? (It's hard to visualize exactly what you are asking)